# Can't install (most recent version of) Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

My Internet Explorer crashes at startup. I tried to install the latest version (IE11 for Windows7) but then I get the puzzling message

[image]

I have a version more recent than the current version installed????
Microsoft also doesn't seem to let me uninstall the corrupted version. What can I do to fix this?

*(I don't care very much about IE -- I'm using Firefox -- but I have programs which try to connect to the internet using IE's engine, and those crash also.)*

---

Windows 7 Home Premium
unknown IE version (probably 9)

Comment: Run a `sfc /scannow` to check your system files. Next try the Microsoft FixIt Portable and use the install/uninstall trpubleshooter. Next try removing/reinstalling IE from the "Add/Remove Windows Features".

Comment: Also, try resetting IE to default settings (Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced > Reset...).

Comment: @BigChris - the sfc seemed to be sufficient: "found corrupt files and successfully repaired them". IE works again. Thanks a bunch. If you make an answer from your comment I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a `sfc /scannow` to check your system files. Next try the Microsoft FixIt Portable and use the install/uninstall troubleshooter. Next try removing/reinstalling IE from the "Add/Remove Windows Features".